# icacls Command regaining Permission by Administrator and Everyone

Tags: windows-server-2012, windows-server-2012-r2, icacls

Accidentally I gave Deny permission to 'Everyone' folder which points to my website. I am using Windows 2012.

Now I get access denied for Administrator and Website shows 500 error.

Can anyone give any icacls command how 'Administrator' get back access to Website D:\website\mysite and 'Everyone' can read/execute the site.

Following the answer It worked to pull up the site once Again. Now I am facing a New Challenge 
**1. To Certain Image Folders only "Administrator" has access no one else. !!**
Means NETWORK SERVICES, SYSTEM, ADMINISTRATORS,USERS are not in the Security List.
[Image Folder Permission Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5v8ej.png)

Can Anyone say How we Include these Access List to the Specified Folders, Please ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may need to take ownership of the directory before you can change permissions on it:

```
takeown /f D:\website\mysite /r /d y
```

(That's /r for recursive, and /d for default answer of y for yes.)

Then you should hopefully be able to run something like:

```
icacls  D:\website\mysite\*.*  /remove:d everyone /T
```

Comment: Is it important to reset ownership to the appropriate process (e.g. SYSTEM for IIS) after fixing permissions? Or could you just give SYSTEM permission on the folder afterwards.

Comment: @Katherine Villyard : thanks ur command worked but, now the website has stopped reading many Images located in (D:\website\mysite\images\restaurant-logos) , (D:\website\mysite\images\com_smartorder\restaurants), (D:\website\mysite\images\slide). Any clue will be helpful. Thanks Again.

Comment: @Katherine Villyard : But Funny it reads (D:\website\mysite\images\com_smartorder\items)

Comment: Hi, I solved the new challenge by Advanced - > Add - > New Principal - > Typed Users etc - > Check Name -> Apply Permissions. Not to mentioned i learned a LOT . Thanks ALL.

Comment: You might also have been able to resolve this by running `icacls <path> /reset /t /c`.